# How to write a try and catch for the following scenario in JAVA

Tags: java, try-catch

When I click on a button -- There are 4 cases:

1. I go straight to where I need to be
2. I get a popup (frame1) I click "ok"  I get another popup (frame2)
3. only get frame1
4. only get frame2

How can I write a try and catch block to handle it?

```
 try {

   myobj.switchFrame(1);

   myobj.click(OKelement);

   myobj.switchFrame(1);

   myobj.Click(OKelement);

 } catch(Exception e)

 {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a try catch block like this. It can help you identify your errors better.

```
try {
     
    //place code here
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    //or
    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
}
```

Comment: How this is different that what I have -- except form printing that msg in the catch block. And what i have does not work. There are 4 cases:

---I go straight to where I need to be
----I get a popup (frame1) I click "ok" I get another popup (frame2)
----only get frame1
-----only get frame2